# convert to timestamp format

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I have a date in the this format : `Aug 18, 2014 15:30:35.246263000`
I want to convert this format to timestamp i.e `2014-8-18 15:30:35.` I don't know how timestamp handle milliseconds. I am using PHP and MySql.

Comment: Trim the milliseconds off the date before converting

Comment: i want milliseconds too

Comment: You can't store milliseconds in a unix timestamp, by definition it's the number of whole seconds since the unix epoch.

Comment: @scragar please give hint on how can i convert the given format into timestamp

Answer (score 3):

Like scragar said, you can't convert exactly your date to a unix timestamp, since the timestamp doesn't support milliseconds. You can however trim the milliseconds and use strtotime, like such:

```
$time  = 'Aug 18, 2014 15:30:35.246263000';
$parts = explode('.', $time);
$timestamp = strtotime($parts[0]);
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
$date = 'Aug 18, 2014 15:30:35.246263000';
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime(substr($date,0,strpos($date,'.'))));
```

You can do it in single line also

```
 echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime(substr('Aug 18, 2014 15:30:35.246263000',0,strpos('Aug 18, 2014 15:30:35.246263000','.'))));
```

Hope it help you :)